# Why is the Rococo `maxCodeSize` too small to do adequate incremental runtime upgrades?

Tags: kusama, rococo, runtime-upgrade

If we want to connect a parachain to Rococo's 'rococo-local' relay chain we follow this [Cumulus tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/connect-parachain/) using [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch). Part of the pre-launch steps mentioned [here](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/pre-launch/#3-minimize-your-runtime-size) is to minimize your runtime size by pruning the functionality, and to then do [incremental upgrades](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/pre-launch/#6-incremental-runtime-deployments) using the generated /target/release/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime.compact.wasm file when the parachain is live to include the missing pallets again.

However, Rococo's relay chain currently has a `maxCodeSize` of only ~3.15 MB, and if you build the [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) using branch 'polkadot_v0.9.17' with `cargo build --release` it generates that file parachain-template-runtime.compact.wasm that is ~2.9 MB. If you add the Sudo pallet to it so you can do the incremental upgrades then building it generates an even larger file of ~3.0 MB, which may not allow enough space for you to do the incremental upgrades to include the missing pallets again during your [launch simulation](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/pre-launch/#7-launch-simulation) on the Rococo production testnet before launching on Kusama's production mainnet.

If you add more pallets than just Sudo and the Scheduler pallet by following [Substrate's Forkless Upgrades](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades/#prepare-an-upgraded-runtime) tutorial then you might exceed the `maxCodeSize` and [Polkadot.js Apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps) may generate an error `Bytes:: Maximum call stack size exceeded` or `Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits` that prevents the runtime upgrade.

Meanwhile, Kusama's relay chain currently has a larger `maxCodeSize` of ~10.5 MB, which may be sufficient to include all your pallets. There would be a requirement for an initial 3.0 MB for the genesis build of substrate-parachain-template branch 'polkadot_v0.9.17' (plus Sudo pallet to allow you to perform runtime upgrades), then a further 1.5 MB for the 1st runtime upgrade to add ~15 pallets like preimage, scheduler, democracy, referenda, conviction voting, council collective, technical collective, elections phragmen, tips, treasury, bounties, child bounties, assets, multisig, identity, proxy, and recovery, and then a further 1.5 MB for a 2nd runtime upgrade to add ~25 of our own custom pallets to increase it a total code size of the parachain-template-runtime.compact.wasm file to ~6 MB, which would still be less than Kusama's `maxCodeSize`.

Note that Chachacha relay chain is alternative production testnet for parachains. But that does not provide an alternative, as it also has the same `maxCodeSize` of as Rococo of ~3.15 MB when you query it [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Ffullnode-relay.chachacha.centrifuge.io#/chainstate) with Polkadot.js Apps by choosing "Developer > Chain state > Storage > configuration (for "selected state query") > activeConfig()" and then clicking the (+) icon.

**Question:** If Rococo's `maxCodeSize` only allows you to make some small runtime upgrades, but isn't large enough for you to add all your missing pallets when your parachain is live on it as [incremental upgrades](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/pre-launch/#6-incremental-runtime-deployments) after pruning them all to minimize the runtime size for genesis, should you just assume that the remaining runtime upgrades will work on Kusama and proceed to doing it on Kusama instead?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the files you are using at genesis and for the upgrade to so a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can be tested?

Comment: Perhaps the `maxCodeSize` could be increased, the best way to do this would be a PR referencing this question and let the core team deliberate and work with you to get it in production 

Comment: In general too, you should ideally keep posts to one succinct question, so the community can provide one (succinct) answer. 

Comment: the files we are using at genesis on Rococo on parachain id 2007 will be included in this PR https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/30. we haven't prepared the runtime upgrade files yet, but they will be generated by restoring the pallets that were pruned in this PR to reduce the x_runtime.compact.wasm file to less than 3.1MB https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you should use the `x_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm` which is about a factor of 3 smaller than the compact wasm. This runtime is compressed with zlib and the node knows to decompress it before execution. Using the compressed Wasm saves space on-chain and over the network.

As for Rococo configuration, that's something that'd be up to the Parity team in charge of the testnet.

Comment: so should the [Forkless Upgrades](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades/#upgrade-the-runtime) tutorial here be updated to say to select the compressed `x_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm` Wasm binary for an upgraded runtime rather than just the `x_runtime.compact.wasm` in production?

Comment: yes, I think the tutorial should be updated to include a note that `compact.compressed.wasm` should be used in the parachain environment.

Comment: Thanks I have created an issue requesting for that change to me made https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/913